# Python, Mysql, Error on inserting a record. Syntax correct

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python

DESCRIPTION:

I have used Tkinter to create an entry form, and the entries are recorded into a database "pythontut.db". I used sqlite3 to connect to the database.

QUESTION:

Whenever I try to add a record to the database, it throws me an error.

> Exception in Tkinter callback
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\rajme\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1702, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)
>     File "", line 1440, in register_new
>       cursor.execute("INSERT INTO PERSON (reg_first, reg_last, reg_email, reg_phone, reg_org,reg_password) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (reg_first, reg_last, reg_email, reg_phone,reg_org,reg_password))
>   sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error

But when I print the values of the entry into python console, it prints perfectly.
Where is the error coming from?

CODE:

```
def register_new():
    global firstname, lastname, org, phone, email, password, password2
    reg_first = firstname.get()
    reg_last = lastname.get()
    reg_email = email.get()
    reg_phone = phone.get()
    reg_org = org.get()
    reg_password = password.get()
    reg_password2 = password2.get()
    print(reg_first, reg_last, reg_email, reg_phone,reg_org,reg_password)
    conn = sqlite3.connect("pythontut.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute ( " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PERSON ( reg_first CHAR(20),reg_last CHAR(20), reg_email CHAR(20),reg_phone CHAR(20),reg_org CHAR(20),reg_password CHAR(20))")        
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO PERSON (reg_first, reg_last, reg_email, reg_phone, reg_org,reg_password) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (reg_first, reg_last, reg_email, reg_phone,reg_org,reg_password))

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it. The solution is to replace '%s' with '?'.